# Filter to check for keyword and display sidebar content accordingly

Tags: php, wordpress

Within Wordpress, is it possible to read the content of a post and look for keywords, then display sidebar content accordingly? Example:

If post content contains the word 'cheese' then don't display sidebar advert, otherwise do.

For extra information, I have >500 posts so would not want to add a tag or custom field to every post.

I'd include examples of code but I'm really not sure whether to start with a regex in functions.php and if so, what do I then look for in the sidebar code?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1 - Stripos seems faster than regex for this purpose [Stripos on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) so I used this.

UPDATE 2 - My current setup...
In index.php (or page.php etc depending on theme):

```
    <?php
    if( has_keyword() ) {
        get_sidebar( 'special' );
    } else {
        get_sidebar( 'normal' );
    }
    ?>
```

and in functions.php

```
function has_keyword ()
{
    global $post;

    $mywords = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3');
    foreach($mywords as $word){

        // return false if post content does not contain keyword
        if( ( stripos( $post->post_content, $word ) === false ) ) {
        return false;
        };
    };
        // return true if it does
        return true;
}; //end function
```

I need to get the foreach function working, there is something wrong in there. I tried to use 'break' on successfully finding a word but I need to return 'false' as well, that's why I added the if condition. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Why not tag the post with cheese, and use `has_term` to check? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term

Comment: @diggy Thanks, but I need to do this check on over 500 existing posts so adding a tag or custom field isn't the way I wanted to go. I'll update the OP.

Comment: This depends on where you are doing it. Are you talking about a single post or page? If you're on the index with all posts, that is a bit trickier.

Comment: @rncrtr Well, I was thinking in functions.php to put a filter that scans the post and sets a variable. If it's set then the sidebar doesn't display the advert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use PHP's [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). Define a custom conditional tag in `functions.php`:

```
function has_keyword( $keyword )
{
    // only check on single post pages
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return false;

    global $post;

    // return false if post content does not contain keyword
    if( ( stripos( $post->post_content, $keyword ) === false ) )
        return false;

    // return true if it does
    return true;
}
```

Then, in your template file:

```
if( has_keyword( 'my_keyword' ) )
    get_sidebar( 'normal' );
else
    get_sidebar( 'special' );
```

**update**

To check for multiple keywords (see comments):

```
function has_keyword()
{
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return false;
    global $post;
    $keywords = array( 'ham', 'cheese' );
    foreach( $keywords as $keyword )
        if( stripos( $post->post_content, $keyword ) )
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: This works well for a single word. Is it possible you can update it for an array? I tried but can't break out of the foreach loop and still return false when a word is found.

Comment: The `has_keyword` function will always return false when NOT viewing single posts or pages. Are you trying to check for the keyword on archive pages that display multiple posts? That is, as @mcrtr said, a bit trickier, and would require a different approach.

Comment: No just with a single post. I have updated the original post, hope you can tweak this.

Comment: what about `if( has_keyword( 'ham' ) || has_keyword( 'cheese' ) )`?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep those words out of the other wp files and just  read in an array in functions.php. Ultimately, I'll add those words into a text box in the admin back end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify against a list of words, you could use this function below, which will return false if any of the words are found in your $content else it will return true. So as to say go ahead and display them ads.

```
function displayAds($content){
    $words = array('cheese', 'ham', 'xxx');
    foreach($words as $word){
       if(preg_match('/\s'.$word.'\s/i', $content)){
          return FALSE;
       };
    };
    return TRUE;
 };
```

then in your index.php you can do as your outloud thinking in your **Update**. Naturally changing function names to reflect your choice of naming.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I went for the stripos solution over regex but +1 for this

Answer (score 1):

you can also use  `preg_match` to find exact keyword match in the string like

```
function check_keyword($keyword){

global $post;

if(!is_single() ){

return false;

}else{

$result = preg_match('/\b('.$keyword.')\b/', $post->post_content);

if($result){

return true;

}else{

return false;

}


}

}
```

To get `side_bar`

Call `check_keyword()`

```
if (check_keyword('cheese')) {
get_sidebar('cheese');
} else {
get_sidebar('no-ads');
}
```

See for reference [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks for your input, I went for the stripos solution purely for speed. +1